# Minecraft cutting out large area with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using 1.8.9, and I need to clear out a large area under ground. I have the coordinates, and I have written a code but it is not working.

In my command block the code is:

```
/fill ~-317.700 ~7.000000 ~-82.700 ~-274.300 ~30.00000 ~-30.374 air
```

My upper diagonal coordinates are (X)-274.300 (Y)30.00000 (Z)-30.374

my lower diagonal coordinates are  (X)-317.700 (Y)7.000000 (Z)-82.700

Answer (score 3):

Your command does not seem to be correct.

```
/fill ~-317.700 ~7.000000 ~-82.700 ~-274.300 ~30.00000 ~-30.374 air
```

the `~` symbol means at player's command block's coordinates. For example, if you want to set a block 1 block above, then you would do:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ stone
```

That would set the co-ords to be same as command blocks, but Y + 1 (*notice the `~1`*).

---

Your command also has decimal coordinates. Blocks always have full coordinates (there can never be a block moved *half-way*. If this was possible, you could see blocks clipping into each other).

---

I actually tried using decimal points with `setblock`, but if I have Y as `50.9`, then the block places at `50`

---

```
/fill -316 7 -82 -274 30 -30 air
```

This is roughly how your command should be. Note: I **rounded the numbers**, so it might not be accurate.

You can use the <kbd>F3</kbd> menu for measuring co-ordinates. However, I recommend using the **Looking at** coordinate which will measure the block you are looking at quite literally.

Answer (score 0):

The area you want to clear depends on your use case.  You have to think about coordinates.

My most common use case is i want to clear a mountain in front of me, but none of the ground under me.

I use

/fill ~-15 ~ ~-15 ~15 ~30 ~15 air